# JSON values from dropdown showing ID numbers instead of strings in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, dropdown

I am trying to submit two dropdown lists with JSON data into my database table. I can get as far as the data inserted into the table but the 'date' and 'time' columns show the ID and parent ID instead of the date and times that are available in the dropdowns. Can anyone tell me why this is? (Main relevant code showing)

```
<?php

session_start();
include('includes/config.php');
error_reporting(0);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $arenadate = $_POST['date'];
  $arenatime = $_POST['time'];
  $useremail = $_SESSION['login'];
  $sql       = "INSERT INTO  tblbooking(userEmail,ArenaDate,ArenaTime) VALUES(:useremail,:date, :time)";
  $query     = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $query->bindParam(':useremail', $useremail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':date', $arenadate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->bindParam(':time', $arenatime, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->execute();
  $lastInsertId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
  if ($lastInsertId) {
    echo "<script>alert('Booking successful.');</script>";
  }
  else {
    echo "<script>alert('Something went wrong. Please try again');</script>";
  }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="contact_form gray-bg">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="control-label">Select Date</label>
            <select name="date" id="date" class="form-control white_bg"
                    data-width="120px" style="color:black" required>
                <option value="">Select Date</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="control-label">Select Time</label>
            <select name="time" id="time" class="form-control white_bg"
                    data-width="120px" style="color:black" required>
                <option value="">Select Time</option>
            </select>
        </div>
      <?php if ($_SESSION['login']) {
        ?>
          <div class="modal-footer text-center">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm Booking"
                     class="btn btn-xs uppercase">
          </div>
      <?php } else { ?>
          <a href="#loginform" class="btn btn-xs uppercase" data-toggle="modal"
             data-dismiss="modal">Login To Book Seat</a>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</section>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function (e) {

    function get_json_data(id, parent_id) {
      var html_code = '';
      $.getJSON('date_list.json', function (data) {
        ListName = id.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + id.substr(1);
        html_code += '<option value="">Select ' + ListName + '</option>';
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
          if (value.parent_id == parent_id) {
            html_code += '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.avail + '</option>';
          }
        });
        $('#' + id).html(html_code);
      });
    }

    get_json_data('date', 0);

    $(document).on('change', '#date', function () {
      var date_id = $(this).val();
      if (date_id != '') {
        get_json_data('time', date_id);
      } else {
        $('#time').html('<option value="">Select Time</option>');
      }
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't it because what gets sent as form data from a select is the value in the "value" attribute of the selected option and not what's inside the tag itself? (unless there is no "value" attribute...) And in your case, what's there is the id?

Comment: @dgig sorry but I am confused. Do i need to change the id to the value attribute?

Comment: I think so - if you're expecting the raw date or time to show up in your $_POST array, then you certainly do.

Comment: @dgig I have a 'date_list.json' file that has each date and time. Would i have to change something within this file?

Comment: I don't think so. I think you might just have to do this: `html_code += '<option value="' + value.avail + '">' + value.avail + '</option>';`

Comment: @dgig I have already tried that. It just stops the time dropdown list from displaying the times

Comment: That shouldn't be - so long as you have "value.avail" (which I assume is the time or date) within the option tag, that should be shown to the user. Unless the value is being referenced in some other way that I don't see here by the javascript - but there's no place I see it being used like that here.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the empty option in #date so that isn't really needed in the html. You can change the following line from:

```
html_code += '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.avail + '</option>';
```

to:

```
html_code += '<option value="' + value.avail + '" data-id="'+value.id+'">' + value.avail + '</option>';
```

The posted value for 'date' and 'time' will be the selected options value attribute, but this will break selecting the date and getting the time based on that id. In this case you could add a data-id attribute and use that to get the time which means the following code would change from:

```
var date_id = $(this).val();
```

to:

```
var date_id = $(this).data('id');
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it still seems to only allow me to view the dates dropdown. What do I include in the data-id attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the `value` attribute of an `<option>` tag unless you want the form to receive that value instead of the visible text.

If you write an option like this inside of a `<select name="date">`:

```
<option value="">Select an option</option>
```

Then the POSTing form will deliver `$_POST['date'] = ''`.

If you write:

```
<option>Select an option</option>
```

Then the POSTing form will deliver `$_POST['date'] = 'Select an option'`.

In terms of form delivery, there is never a need to duplicate the option text as a value.

If you want to store data inside of each `<option>` tag, I'll give the same advice as aCMoFoCord because `data-` attributes are clean and flexible regarding the values that they can hold.

Specifically, I'm saying:

```
function get_json_data(id, parent_id) {
      var html_code = '';
      $.getJSON('date_list.json', function (data) {
        ListName = id.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + id.substr(1);
        html_code += '<option value="">Select ' + ListName + '</option>';
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
          if (value.parent_id == parent_id) {
            html_code += '<option data-id="' + value.id + '">' + value.avail + '</option>';
          }
        });
        $('#' + id).html(html_code);
      });
    }
```

Then:

```
$(document).on('change', '#date', function () {
    if ($(this).val() != '') {
        get_json_data('time', $(this).data('id'));
    } else {
        $('#time').html('<option value="">Select Time</option>');
    }
});
```

Comment: I am unsure what to do with the data- atrribute